# How to keep the connection after closing the extension - chrome extension - python server

Tags: google-chrome, google-apps-script, google-chrome-extension, extension-methods, python-server-pages

Hey I need to build chrome extension with python server and has login and register pages and when I login or register its direct me to a homepage with button disconnect, the only problem I have is when ever I close the extension the connection disconnect how can I keep the connection also when the user close the extension tab?

I have already the login page register page and home page and also myScript.js and sql

here is my server code:
`
class Websocket_Server():

```
def __init__(self, host, port):
    self.server = WebsocketServer(host, port)
    print("server is online!")

def new_client(self, client, server):
    print("New client({}) connected.".format(client["id"]))

def client_left(self, client, server):
    print("Client({}) disconnected.".format(client["id"]))

def message_received(self, client, server, message):
    #print("Client({}) said,{}".format(client["id"], message))
    message_list = message.split(",")
    if(message[0] == "2"):
        self.on_register(client, server, encryptDecrypt(message_list[1]), encryptDecrypt(message_list[2]))
    if(message[0] == "1"):
        self.on_login(client, server, encryptDecrypt(message_list[1]), encryptDecrypt(message_list[2]))

def on_register(self, client, server, email,password):
    print("-----------")
    print(email)
    print(password)
    print("-----------")
    if(ofeksql.check_email_exist(email) == 0):
        ofeksql.insert_row(password,email)
        ws_server.server.send_message(client, "register complete")
        print("register complete")
    elif(ofeksql.check_email_exist(email) == 1):
        ws_server.server.send_message(client, "email already exist")
        print("email already exist")


def on_login(self, client, server, email,password):
    print("-----------")
    print(email)
    print(password)
    print("-----------")
    if(ofeksql.check_email_exist(email) == 0):
        ws_server.server.send_message(client, "email dont exist")
        print("email dont exist")
    elif(ofeksql.check_email_exist(email) == 1):
        if(ofeksql.get_password_email(email) == password):
            ws_server.server.send_message(client, "password correct")
            print("login complete")    
        else:
            ws_server.server.send_message(client, "password incorrect")
            print("register complete")    


def run(self):
    self.server.set_fn_new_client(self.new_client)
    self.server.set_fn_client_left(self.client_left)
    self.server.set_fn_message_received(self.message_received) 
    self.server.run_forever()
```

ws_server = Websocket_Server("localhost" , 8080)
ws_server.run()
`

I stack and don't really know what I should do next and how to fix it.

Comment: Do it in the background script.

Comment: Yes but how can I do it?